# which vmware server is a better choice and which host OS (for QE)

Tags: vmware

we are setting up new QE testing server. I guess host OS will be win2008

Which vmware server to choose - 1.x or 2.x ?

A year ago I tried vmware 1 server with Win2008 and it did not work at all.

However, Vmware server 2 did not seem to have the handy vmware console
VMware Server Console\vmware.exe
(is the new vmware server2 still just web based?)

we have a lot of vmware 1 images, are these ok for v2?

Or is it just better to go with HyperV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyper-V Server or ESXi would probably be the best performing and most trouble free options - ie virtualisation not really dependant on the host operating system (but still free).

You can use tools like [Vmdk2Vhd](http://vmtoolkit.com/blogs/announcements/archive/2006/11/20/vmdk-to-vhd-converter-available.aspx) to convert image files. Be aware that you should boot the image in its old format first and uninstall vmware tools and some drivers like specific disk controller drivers (as per the instructions of the tool) before you convert it.

Going the enterprise route the System Center Virtual Machine Manager can do this mostly automatically, but then it's not a free solution anymore :) This platform can of course also do physical to virtual migrations for you...

...but alas, you can prepare a physical machine the same way as before converting a vmware image and then use normal imaging tools to clone it into a virtual machine. Or you can use Vmware's [free converter tool](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) and then convert the resulting vmdk image to vhd :)

Comment: Agree, we went with VMware server initially and decided to upgrade to ESXi within a few weeks.

Comment: I will install Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2008,   however two questions:   Can I convert VMWARE images for it somehow?  Can I virtualize my existing win2003 server there?

Answer (score 0):

Vmware Server v2 can use v1 images. Windows Server 2008 is supported only in v2. v2 also includes the Virtual Infrastructure Client which you can use instead of the web access ( the client replaces the old console from v1). This is the same client that is used with ESX.

Answer (score 0):

vmware 2.0 crashed regularly on one server I have - however, hasn't crashed since the recent 2.0.1 update (but its only been a week).

I have w2K8 running under vmware 1.0.9 - by selecting Vista (experimental) as the OS setting.  However, it's not under any load yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend ESXi over VMware Server (you can migrate the images) purely for performance reasons. Server 2008 and Vista both run *abysmally* under VMware Server from my experience. With ESXi and a decent hardware RAID setup, things can be a bit more bearable.